# A word meaning 'conforming to principles, hence effective'

Tags: single-word-requests

Do we have a word that means 'effective/promising due to its conformity to principles [established in a given field of activity, etc]? An example context *could* be:

> There remain a number of pressing questions, demanding [?] decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [competent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Competent)  comes close to what you are looking for: (from TFD)

> - properly or sufficiently qualified:  a competent speech.
> - suitable or sufficient for the purpose: a competent answer.

[Competence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/competence):

> - The state or quality of being adequately or well qualified;

- There remain a number of pressing questions, demanding competent  decisions.